# ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (2, 200, 200, 3) where an element of shape (4, 200, 200, 3) was expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.x

I construct my generator function with batch_size = 4  like below:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(img_gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes = ([4,200,200,3],[4,2]))
```

After running, I find this error

```
ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (2, 200, 200, 3) where an element of shape (4, 200, 200, 3) was expected.
```

I can't undrestand why ?

Comment: Because `img_gen` yields the wrong elements? Without that generator it's hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is the number of data examples is not divisible by the batch size. Either arrange your data to be a multiple of batch size or, better, have the subsequent code work with any batch size.